# New To Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order

I am new to Star Trek. Well, I have seen random episodes here and there, but I have never fully watched a series. I am curious as to where I should start in my new adventure as there are several different series/movies out there. If anyone could give me suggestions that would be wonderful!

Comment: What the hell is going on?  Is one person just making a bunch of different logins simply to ask the same question?  This is the _fourth_ time I've seen this question today.